# Order custom post type by custom field (created by PODS) via PHP

Tags: get-posts

I have this PHP code:

```
$posts = get_posts([
      'post_type' => 'clen',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'numberposts' => -1,
      'orderby' => 'funkcia',
      'order'    => 'DESC'
    ]);
```

However, this code does not sort the posts by `funkcia` field at all.

What is wrong with my code, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following code:

```
$posts = get_posts([
        'post_type'         => 'clen',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'          => 'funkcia',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'order'             => 'ASC'
    ]);
```

This snippet orders the gotten posts by field `funkcia`.